# Attach to process WCF service from another machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

I'm trying attach to WCF service which is published at Windows Server 2008.
I have this WCF at my machine with XP. I have some weird errors at server and I want to attach to this wcf from server with Windows Server 2008.

I can't find good tutorial aobut this issue.

Could you recommend me good tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx), basically you install a small client on the remote machine and connect to it from your machine.